# Modify web page frame size with TamperMonkey UserScript

Tags: css, iframe, tampermonkey

My son's virtual Spanish class has his text book in a horribly small frame that you have to scroll inside of instead of using the full height of the browser window.

I've looked at the code and found that if I change the style height for the d2l-iframe (4th to last line) from the fixed 760px to 87vh it looks perfect on his monitor. It's such a minor correction but I can't figure out how to get TamperMonkey change it. I've Googled and tried several approaches to no avail.

I'm really just looking for someone with TamperMonkey/UserScripts experience to point me in the right direction but I'd like to get there myself.

```
<div class="d2l-popup d2l-popup-nopadding">
        <div class="d2l-popup-title">
            <div class="d2l_1_0_821 d2l_1_1_366 d2l-hidden" id="d2l-popup-nav">
                <div class="d2l-iterator">
                    <a class="d2l-iterator-button d2l-iterator-button-prev d2l-iterator-button-notext" role="button" href="/d2l/le/content/303492/navigateContent/2779/Previous?pId=4043417" title="Previous "><d2l-icon icon="tier1:chevron-left" dir="ltr"></d2l-icon><span class="d2l-offscreen">Previous </span>&nbsp;</a><a class="d2l-iterator-button d2l-iterator-button-next d2l-iterator-button-notext" role="button" href="/d2l/le/content/303492/navigateContent/2779/Next?pId=4043417" title="Next"><span class="d2l-offscreen">Next</span>&nbsp;<d2l-icon icon="tier1:chevron-right" dir="ltr"></d2l-icon></a></div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="d2l-heading vui-heading-1">01.00 Un viaje se mide mejor en amigos que en millas</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="d2l-popup-body" style="height: 709px;">
            <div class="d2l-messagearea d2l_1_2_876" id="d2l_messagearea" role="alert" tabindex="0"></div><div>
                <div class="d2l-iframe-loading-container d2l_1_4_428 d2l_1_5_609" style="display: none;">
                </div>
                <iframe class="d2l-iframe d2l_1_4_428 d2l_1_5_609" id="d2l_1_3_744" name="d2l_1_3_744" src="/d2l/common/dialogs/quickLink/quickLink.d2l?ou=303492&amp;type=lti&amp;rCode=0e28c0388c4f4923851fc7eb-12&amp;contentTopicId=4043435&amp;d2l_body_type=3" title="01.00 Un viaje se mide mejor en amigos que en millas" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen="" allow="microphone *; camera *; autoplay *" onload="this.m_loaded=true;" data-default-height="580" style="height: 87vh;width: 100%;"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a userscript that changes the html of it.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        www.whateverpage.com
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

//below code selects the html class that stores the height element and //changes the width same thing can be done with height.
//if its an id then do document.getElementByID("idhere");
//if class then do document.querySelector("classhere").height = "760";
document.querySelector(".d21-popup-body").width = "760";
```

I hope this helps but if it didn't I would suggest looking up DOM manipulation with html
But for your situation search up changing width and height with dom js
Understanding the DOM would probably help you a lot